# chartJs: I want to show both of the dataset legends when i hover to one of the points?

Tags: d3.js, chart.js

[image: current behaviour]

I'm new to using it. Plus i've started the month with hard code labels ranging from jan to december. How Can i range the labels from january to now. 
Another problem is like you can see in the picture when i hover to a point. Only that point tooltop is shown i want to see all the points tooltip that land on the same line

Code

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
  ctx.height = 50;
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
          labels: monthNames,
          datasets: [{
              label: "Sales",
              data: [2000, 1200, 3000, 5000, 1000, 1300],
              pointHoverBackgroundColor:  'rgb(255, 99, 132)',  
              backgroundColor: [
                  'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
              ],
              borderColor: [
                  'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                  'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                  'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                  'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                  'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                  'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
              ],
              borderWidth: 1
          },
          {
              label: "gross sales",
              data: [1500, 2200, 3000, 2800, 1122, 2345],
              pointHoverBackgroundColor:  'rgb(66, 133, 244)',   
              backgroundColor: [
                  'rgb(66, 133, 244, 0.2)',                 
              ],
              borderColor: [
                  'rgb(66, 133, 244)',                  
              ],
              borderWidth: 1
          }]
      },
      options: {
        title:{
          display: "true",
          text: "Sales Reports",
          fontSize: "22"
        },
        tooltips:{
          intersect: false
        },
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
      }
```

});

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the hover intersect property to achieve this. Here is a fiddle for you -> http://jsfiddle.net/6n3w0qkh/5/.

Hope it helps!

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");  
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
          labels: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'],
          datasets: [{
              label: "Sales",
              data: [2000, 1200, 3000, 5000, 1000, 1300],
              pointHoverBackgroundColor:  'rgb(255, 99, 132)',  
              backgroundColor: [
                  'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
              ],
              borderColor: [
                  'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                  'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                  'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                  'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                  'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                  'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
              ],
              borderWidth: 1
          },
          {
              label: "gross sales",
              data: [1500, 2200, 3000, 2800, 1122, 2345],
              pointHoverBackgroundColor:  'rgb(66, 133, 244)',   
              backgroundColor: [
                  'rgb(66, 133, 244, 0.2)',                 
              ],
              borderColor: [
                  'rgb(66, 133, 244)',                  
              ],
              borderWidth: 1
          }]
      },
      options: {
        title:{
          display: "true",
          text: "Sales Reports",
          fontSize: "22"
        },
        tooltips: {
            mode: 'index',
            intersect: false
        },
        hover: {
            mode: 'nearest',
            intersect: true
        },
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
      }
});
```

Comment: Also about the labels, you can compute the months till now, store it an array using JS or maybe from something else, and provide it in the labels array.

Comment: Thanks can you please also help me with this? .. <canvas id="myChart" width="200" height="200"></canvas> i cannot change the width of my canvas. I tried putting it inside a container and gave that container a specific height and width.. unable to achieve this

Comment: First remove the height specified ctx element in the javascript code, and set the maintainAspectRatio to false in the chart option and responsive to true. Then wrap the canvas inside a div and supply dimensions then it should take the dimensions of the div.

Comment: I cannot post code since answering from phone, if you cannot figure out let me know I will try to share the code as soon as I can.

Comment: Thanks a lot man.. I just figured it out. quite new to this thing. Kunal can you help me some other time later? If i have some problem on chart js i will ask you if i get no where.. where can i add you ?

Comment: I cannot actually post my contact information here, if you run into problem you can post on stackoverflow only and place a request to answer to me. I will get a notification and surely try to answer.